# csvtojson npm is rounding 7945160000000000 to 7.95E+15

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, npm, csvtojson

i am getting rounded values as string from csv, i don't want values to get rounded of i need the exact value from the csv is there any way?

```
(async() => {
  try {
    let csvInUsers = []
    const jsonArray = await csv({
      trim: true
    }).fromFile(csvFilePath);

    //////     Invalid CSV   /////
    if (typeof jsonArray[0]['_id'] == 'undefined' ||
      typeof jsonArray[0]['playerId'] == 'undefined') {
      let error = new Error('Uploaded csv is invalid.');
      error.statusCode = 400;
      error.code = 'INVALID_CSV';
      fs.unlinkSync(csvFilePath);
      return cb(error);
    }
    //////     Invalid CSV   /////

    async.eachSeries(jsonArray, function(value, callback) {
      (async() => {
        try {
          UserCollection.updateOne({
            _id: ObjectId(value._id)
          }, {
            $set: {
              playerId: String(value.playerId)
            }
          })
          callback(null)
        } catch (error) {
          if (error) console.log(error);
          callback(error)
        }
      })();
    }, (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      fs.unlinkSync(csvFilePath);
      cb()
    });
  } catch (error) {
    cb(error)
  }
})();
```

7945160000000000 getting rounded to 7.95E+15 i was expecting the exact value in csv getting read

Comment: original playerId from csv is 7945160000000000

Comment: but it is getting converted to 7.95E+15 after reading

Comment: is csvtojson some library? if so, it's not very good then, is it

Comment: i think its your csv, if you open your csv file via notepad / text editor you will get the *7.95E+15*` value

Comment: if i open the csv file via sublime it shows 7945160000000000 and csvtojson is an npm

Comment: the code in the question works as required, the problem is something else

Comment: are you sure the npm is returning the exact value?

Comment: Sorry the issue was with my csv the above code was working perfectly thanks @JairoMalanay